# "Авторство статей принадлежит ведущим специалистам, каждого в своём вопросе" - можно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Уникальное издание, чья дальнейшая судьба пока неизвестна. Первый том
>   вышел в 2000 году. “С самого начала энциклопедия планировалась как
>   издание, далеко выходящее за рамки православного мира: в нём должны
>   были быть представлены основные сведения по всем христианским
>   конфессиям и иным вероисповеданиям, значительные материалы из области
>   философии, морали, этики, искусства, музыки”. **Авторство статей
>   принадлежит ведущим специалистам, каждого в своём вопросе.** В работе
>   по созданию энциклопедии участвуют: Московская духовная академия,
>   институты Российской академии наук, Московский, Санкт-Петербургский и
>   ряд других крупнейших региональных университетов, синодальные комиссии
>   и отделы Московской Патриархии, РАН, а также научные центры США,
>   Греции и Италии. В настоящее время выпущено 40 томов (с учётом
>   неалфавитного тома — 41-го). В частности: "Православная энциклопедия. Том
>   XXVIII". Всё об искусстве Италии. Коротко и с последними датировками.

Пожалуйста, увидите ошибки - свистните!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Авторство статей принадлежит ведущим специалистам, (специализация) каждого в своей области.**

Или: Авторство статей принадлежит ведущим специалистам —  каждого в своей области.

Тире чётко обозначает присоединение, но не смотрится  в этом тексте. В то же время читать предложение (при постановке запятой или тире)  надо с подчеркнутой паузой.

**Пояснение**

1) Обособленный оборот похож на присоединительную конструкцию, тогда согласование в падеже не требуется. А при согласовании  теряется смысл, тогда оборот действительно лучше убрать. Оставить — "ведущим специалистам в соответствующих вопросах/областях".

2) Сочетание "специалист в своем вопросе" как-то мало употребляется, обычно — в своей области, в своем деле, в области чего-то.

Answer (score 1):

По самому вопросу: мне не нравится такое согласование падежей. Нельзя ли убрать слово "каждого"? Например, "...ведущим специалистам в соответствующих вопросах".

**(с учётом неалфавитного тома — 41-го)**

Предлагаю: или "(с учётом неалфавитного тома — 41)" или "(без учёта неалфавитного тома — 41-го)". Иначе арифметика не сходится :)

**Московский, Санкт-Петербургский и ряд других крупнейших региональных университетов**

Здесь непонятно, о чём идёт речь. Это было бы правильно, если бы в Москве был только один университет. Если имеется в виду МГУ, то так и нужно говорить, если разные московские — тогда во множественном числе.

Comment: Как может _не нравиться_ то, чего нет совсем? Не со словом же "авторство", искать падежного согласования :)

Comment: @Alex_ander Да, конечно. Что-то мне там не нравилось, а как правильно придраться, не придумал. Сонный был, наверное :) С Наступающим всех!

Comment: C наступающим!!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Банальная ошибка в падеже, надо "кажд**ому**" (согл. с "принадлежит") и после "каждому" - тире (опущено "специалисту").
2. По стилю. Дальнейшая судьба которого (чья - излишне "одушевлённая" для издания принадлежность судьбы). Либо тематка издания за рамки мира, либо издание за рамки православной тематики (сейчас издание как бы раздается за пределами мира).
3. "Неалфавитный" похоже на окказионализм, возможно, лучше ***вне***алфавитный.